# find the python script from memory of python process

Tags: python, linux, memory, gdb

I am developing a product and I need to find the script code in ram of the python process. Is there any chance I can use gdb tool for reading the 
address that points to the scripts in memory or at least printing all strings variables of python process?

I already tried to read the /proc/pid of python/maps and then use the
gdb to read the address but it didn't work:

```
gdb -p my-python-pid-process
dump binary memory FILE address-from-/proc/pid/maps/start address-from-/proc/pid/maps/end
```

And I am getting an error that say 
"can't access the address"